# FaxCOmExlib and IIS 7

Tags: windows, iis-7, fax

I have a small web service, which should send faxes. The code for this web service is working fine when it is not in the wwwroot folder. However, once I add this service to the IIS,
I always get FaxDocument exception when I call that service.
I think the problem is in the permissions somewhere. 
Can anyone suggest how can I configure my web service to use the FaxComExLib library? 
What permissions should I set?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I'm familiar with this exception, but there is a page documenting commmon FAXCOMEXLib problems and solutions by InterFax:

http://www.interfax.net/en/dev/faxcomexlib

This page assembles solutions from major technical Web fourms and includes links to the discussions). It might include some info that will help you with the permissions issue.